# How to develop a Dart library locally?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I might be having a mental eclipse, but it's hard for me to do the simplest thing: *write a simple library and use it*. (I want to do this all locally, without publishing the library, etc.)

I've browsed through the list of [pub commands](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/index.html) and none seems to install a package locally, so how can I use it in other projects?

For example, I just cloned [this library](https://github.com/dart-lang/barback/tree/master/example/simple_transformer) and would like to test it locally to see if it works. How can I do that?

Comment: It seems you confuse package and library. In Dart a package consists of one or more libraries, also a package with only resource files without any library is possible. A library is a Dart script file. There could also be additional files be part of that library (connected with `part`/`part of`. If you want to use a library within the same package, just import it `import 'some_library_file.dart';`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To use a local library, you can specify a [local filepath](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#path-packages) in your pubspec, such as:

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    path: /Users/me/transmogrify
```

When using a local dependency, Dart will pick up any changes automatically, so there's no need to run a special `pub` command.

Comment: Why does it sound absurd? It's a single-line change to do exactly what you want. Honestly, in my opinion requiring a separate pub command to link a local package would be more absurd :)

Comment: yet all other package managers I know work this way. They have a repo and you fill it, either from the web as dependencies, or from any other source. Maven, npm, dub, ...

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely common - I'm just not convinced it's any better. :) For what it's worth, npm supports using [local filepaths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) this same way. And I don't think I would point to Maven as an example of a modern package manager done right... ;-)

Comment: What I don't like with this approach is that I don't want to change the `pubspec` file to use my local version of a _git repo_ type dependency. e.g.: In a JS package, [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) let me use packages locally without modifying the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [path packages](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#path-packages).

Comment: Why do you think that? I strongly recommend you to read all the article linked to better understand the dependency system used in pub and all the possibilities it offers.

Comment: I just want to create a lib and use it. This way forces me to remember where I store it, because I can't publish it / install it. Anyways, it's more like a makefile than a dependency manager I guess

Comment: Keep in in the same place as your pubspec if you want. the "path:" config accepts relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify also relatively with the name of the package, e.g.:

```dart
dependencies:
   my_other_package:
      path: ../my_other_package
```