# How to write a builder for flutter like json_serializable

Tags: dart, flutter, metaprogramming, code-generation, dart-pub

I want do some code gen work with flutter.

I found `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` can do code gen work.

But in the document: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build_runner say: "build_runner can only run Builders that are published with a build.yaml file."

I want to known how to make a custom builder or anything else to gen dart code like json_serializable.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not just look at the source for that package? https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable

Comment: I have seen this. But this is a "published" package, need to known how to use a local package. Do you have any links about this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're missing.  Look at the source code for `json_serializable`, and do the same thing locally.

Comment: Now,I known my real don't know is: How to create a dart package in Android Studio. And How to use local dart package in Flutter project.  After hard try on this: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages   And this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652422/how-to-develop-a-dart-library-locally.  Finally Success!!! Thank you!!